# Best way to search through a very big dataset?

Tags: search, full-text-search

I have text files that contain about 12gbs worth of tweets and need to search through this dataset off of keywords. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Familiar with Java, Python, R. I don't think my computer can handle the files if, for example,  I do some sort of script that goes through each text file in python

Answer (score 1):

"Oh, Python, or any other language, can most-certainly do it."  Might take a few seconds, but the job will get done.  I suggest that the best approach to your problem is:  "straight ahead."  Write scripts that process the files one line at a time.

Although "12 gigabytes" sounds enormous to *us,* to any modern-day machine it's really not that big at all.

Build hashes (associative arrays) in memory as needed.  Generally avoid database-operations (other than "SQLite" database files, maybe ...), but, if you happen to find yourself needing "indexed file storage," SQLite is a terrific tool.

. . . with one very-important caveat:  "when using SQLite, *use transactions,* even when reading."  By default, SQLite will physically-commit every write and physically-verify every read, *unless* you are in a transaction.  Then, and only then, it will "lazy read/write," as you might have expected it to do all the time.  (And then, "that sucker's *f-a-s-t...!"*)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be exact, then you need to see at every file once, so if your computer can't take that load, then say goodbye to exactness.

---

Another approach, would be to use [approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) which are faster than the exact ones, but come in the expense of loosing accuracy.

That should get you started and I will stop my answer here, since the topic is just too broad to continue with from here.